# AJAX failing even though it's not failing?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm running an AJAX function like I've done before.  This time it's strange.  While the XHR console gives me 200/Success, the error callback keeps happening.

```
function runNewprop() {
   var nurl = 'http://www.mysite.com/myscript.php';

$.ajax({
    url: nurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $('#nl_details').html('');
        $each(data, function (key, value){
            var mlsnum = value[0];

            $('#nl_details').append('<div class="nl_list"><h5>'+mlsnum+'</h5></<div>');
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Oops!');
    }
});
}
```

Then the PHP file:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
mysql_select_db('singleprop', $link);
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['date']);
$sort = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sort']);
$query = "
    SELECT * FROM jos_mls
        JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON singleprop.jos_mls.MSTLISTBRD = active.AGENTUID
        JOIN jos_agents AS agents ON active.AGENTUID = agents.AGTBRDIDMM
    ";

if ($date == 'week') {
    $query .= "AND MSTLISTDT >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)";
}
elseif ($date == 'twoweek') {
    $query .= "AND MSTLISTDT >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 DAY)";
}
elseif ($date == 'month') {
    $query .= "AND MSTLISTDT >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -31 DAY)";
}
elseif ($date == 'twomonth') {
    $query .= "AND MSTLISTDT >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -62 DAY)";
}



if ($sort == 'agent') {
    $query .= " ORDER BY AGTLNAME";
}
elseif ($sort == 'city') {
    $query .= " ORDER BY MSTCITY";
}
elseif ($sort == 'zip') {
    $query .= " ORDER BY MSTZIP";
}
elseif ($sort == 'county') {
    $query .= " ORDER BY MSTCOUNTY";
}
else {
    $query .= " ORDER BY MSTLISTDT";
}

$query .= ";";


$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
return json_encode($data);

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Am I missing something in my syntax?  When I echo out the built query and copy it to my console and run it, everything goes smooth.  But when I try to run this through AJAX, I get success/200, but the error callback happens.

Comment: You want your PHP script to `echo` the data, not `return` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your PHP is not outputting valid JSON. You specified `json` as the datatype in the ajax call, this means jQuery will fire the `error` function if it could not parse the resulting JSON.

In your PHP you should be echoing not returning, change to:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

Also verify nothing else is being outputted (such as error or notice messages).

Finally, as @whirlwin points out, you have the `$.each` syntax error in the success function, while this isn't your root problem, it will become a problem when you fix the JSON output.

Comment: Well, I'm getting back data now, just not the data that I wanted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in the success callback. Change the following line:

```
$each(data, function (key, value){
```

to

```
$.each(data, function (key, value){
```

Comment: Ok, so obviously, this was my fault.

Instead of posting stuff here, which I know this isn't used for, is there a place where people help each other in error checking code?  Another site or perhaps a different post tag?

Comment: I think just posting the errors when they occur (like you did) is the best approach, and different people will point out different problems.

Comment: Well, I've gotten down votes or had posts deleted for different things, and I guess it just amounts or what mood people are in?  I just don't want to add clutter and be a "help vampire" as the meta says.

Comment: It depends, I guess. Sometimes when the errors are caused by very basic mistakes, it might indicate that you haven't debugged it enough yourself. I'm not saying you haven't, but that is how some people see it.